# SSRS SharePoint List outputting HTMl format for a field. How to remove HTML tags so it just shows the content

Tags: html, sharepoint, format, ssrs-2008

I have a microsoft sharepoint list and I am trying to output this into an SSRS report. Most fields work, however one particular field that doesnt is seen in the iamge below where it outputs HTML? How can I format this so it only displays whats in the P tag?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - if you click on the row you want to remove the HTML for, and right click on placeholder properties, under markup type there is something called HTML - Interpret HTML Tags as Styles.